# How is the value calculated when using parseInt with minus

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain why the value is not calculated wrong? Please be aware of the fact that I cannot change the value that goes into the function. If that is needed to change please give side note how it should work ideally.

Here is the code. The code will explain whats wrong

```js
function getPrice(price){
 console.log(price,"- 4,13 =", parseInt(price) - 4.13);
  $('p').html(parseInt(price) - 4.13);
}

getPrice(39,50);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="result"> </p>
<span>// Result should be: 35,37 </span>
```

Can someone please help me explain this :)

Comment: I think you need to replace `,` with `.` in function argument

Comment: you're not passing 39.50 as an argument, but two arguments, 39 and 50 respectively

Comment: Life is difficult for many Europeans who have to switch between comma and dot when coding. ;-)

Comment: @trincot I know xd

Comment: `parseInt` even if it's meant to be `.` and not `,` doesn't make sense, if you want to parse floating point, it's `parseFloat`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `,` with `.` .in your function argument (but in your code you are using parseInt and it will ignore the value after `,` or '.').

Note: When you use parseInt, it will try to parse the value until it find string which cannot be converted to int. In this case parseInt parsed the value to `39`.

> If you are passing `float` value in argument then change 'parseInt' to `parseFloat`

```js
function getPrice(price){
 console.log(price,"- 4,13 =", parseFloat(price) - 4.13);
  //$('p').html(parseInt(price) - 4.13);
}

getPrice(39.50);
getPrice("39,50".replace(',', '.')) // number with ,
```

Comment: But like I said what if I cannot change this part: `getPrice(39.50);` I need to stick to: `getPrice(39,50);`

Comment: then replace the `,` with `.` using `replace`